# Reducing overhead of thread context switching in multithreaded application

Tags: android, arm

I am observing roughly the following trend in a multi-threaded application

```
No. of threads:  2
Application time: 5s 

No. of threads: 4 
Application time: 10s 

No. of threads: 8 
Application time: 20s 

No. of threads: 16 
Application time: 40s
```

1-What could be the reason for the increasing application time (given that I don't have any other application running, and I have enough resources)?

2-I guess the increased application time is due to increased thread-context-switching overhead. If I am correct What are the ways to reduce this context switching overhead?

Profiler is not giving me any insight at thread level.

**Platform Information**

Android, running on ARM Cortex-A8

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing what you're doing in those threads. The easy-to-assume answer is when you add new threads, these new threads are not relieving execution burden from the others, they're doing new work which would not otherwise be performed.

In 40 seconds of run time, with 16 threads, you are not going to notice the effect of context switching unless you're also counting actual units of work performed and those units of work take a small amount of time.